# How to not display Prev Button & Next Button in Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted if First Slide of slider is showing to user Prev Button shouldn't show & when Last Slide is showing, Next Button shouldn't show ...

I have wrote these codes but doesn't work ... :

Note: Every Slide that has .ji-active Class, Shows to user ...

```
if ($('.ji-slider div:last').hasClass('ji-active')) {
    $('.ji-next-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {
    $('.ji-next-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

if ($('.ji-slider div:first').hasClass('ji-active')) {
    $('.ji-pre-btn').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {
    $('.ji-pre-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

What is my mistake ?

This is my HTML :

```
        <div class="ji-slider" data-animation="fadeIn">
            <div class="ji-active">
                <img src="Images/Slider (1).png">
                <p class="ji-caption">This Is First !</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="Images/Slider (2).png">
                <p class="ji-caption">This Is Second !</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="ji-pre-btn">&#10094;</button>
            <button type="button" class="ji-next-btn">&#10095; </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: where you are defining these functions?. It should be inside `.ji-next-btn` or `.ji-pre-btn` click function.

Comment: @AwladLiton Here you are ...

Comment: @The_ehT Thanks for your response but problem is that when page loads & First Slide shows to user, It won't remove Pre Button

Comment: so simple you hide it when page loads.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the button is visible or its just that the space alloted for that button is still there, though the button is not visible.? Coz css('visibility', 'hidden') and css('display', 'none') are two different things. You are using the former which will render the button, reserve the space for the button, but not display it i.e., wont allow other containers to take its place.

Comment: @The_ehT It is one problem, Abother problem is that my If statement doesn't work too ..., For example I have Two Slides, When I click Next Button & shows me Second Slide, It hide Next Btn but when I return to First Slide It will hide Pre Btn & doesn't show the Next Btn too ...

Comment: So the problem is either in your code where you add or remove `ji-active` class or where you are wrapping the given js codes.

Comment: @The_ehT I tried everything but ...

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi Thanks my friend but my question is for hiding by "Visibility" or "Display" ..., No Difference ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple css, left arrow hidden for first slide and right arrow for last =)

**if it didn't work add `!important` like `visibility: hidden !important;`**

select first slide with class `.ji-active` than go to sibling with class `.ji-pre-btn` and hide, for last slide i use `:last-of-type` selector because you need select last div if use `:last-child` then be selected "next" button.

sorry for my bad English.

```css
img{
  display:block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ji-slider{
  background-color: #eee;
}
.ji-slider > div:first-child.ji-active ~ .ji-pre-btn{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.ji-slider > div:last-of-type.ji-active ~ .ji-next-btn{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="ji-slider" data-animation="fadeIn">
            <div class="ji-active">
                <img src="Images/Slider (1).png">
                <p class="ji-caption">This Is First !</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="Images/Slider (2).png">
                <p class="ji-caption">This Is Second !</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="ji-pre-btn">&#10094;</button>
            <button type="button" class="ji-next-btn">&#10095; </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Great help my friend, I don't know how to thank you ... Again Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<div class="ji-slider" data-animation="fadeIn"> <div class="ji-active first_slide"> <img src="Images/Slider (1).png"> <p class="ji-caption">This Is First !</p> </div> <div class=last_slide> <img src="Images/Slider (2).png"> <p class="ji-caption">This Is Second !</p> </div> <button type="button" class="ji-pre-btn">&#10094;</button> <button type="button" class="ji-next-btn">&#10095; </button> </div>
If($(".first_slide").css("display") == "block"){
    $(".ji-pre-btn").hide();
    $(".ji-next-btn").show();
}else{
    $(".ji-pre-btn").show();
    $(".ji-next-btn").hide();
}

$(".ji-next-btn").click(function(){
$(".first_slide").hide();
});

$(".ji-pre-btn").click(function(){
$(".first_slide").show();
});
```